# Topic Creating within Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap

I was wondering how I can create a topic in the console of fire base. I see there is android code to do it from the application but that takes time to reflect on the console. I don't even know where to look if it was created. Also can this be done in Javascript compared to java?

Example code for JS would be nice if I cannot do it through the console.

Thanks,

Comment: What sort of topic?  For Cloud Messaging?  For Cloud PubSub?

Comment: Cloud Messaging

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything in the console to create a topic. Just start using it by string name on both the server and client, and it will just work.

Comment: How do I see that the topic was created from a visual representative?

Comment: You see the messages arrive on the device after they're sent.

Comment: I am not receiving the notification. I am sending the push through c# code. And I am registering to a topin using js code. I am using phone gap.